# What is the ideal way to install VMware and VMWare Tools for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, vmware, rails

I have downloaded **VMware-player-5.0.1-894247.exe** from  [this Official Website](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0)  . Also downloaded **Ubuntu 12.10** from [Ubuntu official website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Now, **here comes my Pain.**

I have installed VMware and then chose to install Ubuntu by Mounting the ISO file instead of choosing **I will install later**. Now ubuntu take approx 30-40 mins to get installed and after that I go to VMware setting and **share** my workspace (one of ruby on rails project), that I need in VMware for further development. But when i browse from home/mnt i cannot see `hgfs` folder. **I cannot see my shared folder anywhere**. From the past 2 weeks I'm trying my best to get my project inside VMware. BUT I can't get it. I have again reinstalled VMware tools.. but once i got a message: `as shared folder is not enabled` (somewhhat.. I don't remember what was the message, but it was related to shared).

Please guide me as I want to start working on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share usb device too. You have to install virtualbox additions and after run this command:

```
sudo gpasswd -a yourname vboxusers
```

Change yourname with the name of real Linux User. After that, you must reboot.

Comment: Please note that the OP question is about VMWare, not virtualbox.

Comment: thanks Eric ...but as arielf suggested...i need a solution to get my mnt/hgfs/project in my terminal ...pls advice!!!